How to get text of an element SAP GUI scripting
Im starting with SAP scripting, I need to get text of an element that script recording captured as: session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlSINWP_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell/shellcont[0]/shell")
how can I achieve this ??
I tried with:
val = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlSINWP_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell/shellcont[0]/shell").text
MsgBox val
and I get "SAPGUI.GridViewCtrl.1"
But in sap window this element contains for example "00000564773-5/2/24"

It seems that you are dealing with ALVGRID control , i.e. something like GRID1.GetCellValue(sapRow,"<COLNAME>") should give you the content of the cell where set GRID1 = session.findById("wnd[0]/usr/cntlSINWP_CONTAINER/shellcont/shell/shellcont[1]/shell/shellcont[0]/shell")should give access to the grid.

Great!! This was exactly what I was looking for, I just had to add a watch to look for the COLNAME because it was not the same as shown in SAP, but once I get it it works perfectly. I will continue learning SAP Scripting, thanks a lot !!!
